# Select subset of objects from javascript object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I've got a long array of objects:

```
var myObj = {
  a: "aaa",
  b: "bbb",
  c: "ccc",
  d: "ddd",
  ...
}
```

I'd like to create a new object array that consists of every object except the first two:

```
var myObj2 = {
  c: "ccc",
  d: "ddd",
  ...
}
```

Obviously `myObj.slice(2)` doesn't work (as much as I'd like it to), and I can't select them all by name (`myObj.c, myObj.d, etc`) because there are more than 100 objects, and potentially more to be added.

What's the best way to select a range of objects in a object array?

Comment: There's no such thing as the "first two" properties. The order of properties in a object is not guaranteed.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Oy. So it has to be by key name, huh?

Comment: I see just one object here, not an array.  There is no such thing as an "object array", although you could have an array of objects.  `slice` isn't working because `slice` is an array method, not an object method.

Comment: Also mention the formula. It is not necessary to be a KEY name..It could be value as well..

Comment: Are your keys necessarily "a", "b", etc.?  Or something that could be sorted alphabetically?

Comment: @jmargolisvt census table names - "B0010001","B0030001", etc. Definitely sortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to recompose this, but here is a general approach.

First, here's your object with some sortable keys:

```
var obj = {B201: "apple", B342: "orange", B123: "pear"}
```

Then create an array of the first two keys after sorting:

```
var arr = Object.keys(obj).sort().slice(0,2);
```

This returns `["B123", "B201"]`.

Define a function that removes the object property based on the key name:

```
function remove (e, i, a) {delete obj[e];};
```

Then call that function for each property:

```
arr.forEach(remove);
```

You should get the object with the "first two" properties removed:

```
Object {B342: "orange"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below method to remove the keys you don't want

```
var myObj = {a: "aaa",b: "bbb",c: "ccc",d: "ddd"}

function filterObject(obj,filterObject){
    var newObj = {}
    for(key in obj){
        if(!filterObject[key]){
            newObj[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    return newObj;
}

console.log(filterObject(myObj,{a:true,b:true}))
```

Sample Output:

```
{ c: 'ccc', d: 'ddd' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have an array of objects like this

```
myObj = [
                {
                  a: "aaa",
                  b: "bbb",
                  c: "ccc",
                  d: "ddd",
                  ...
                },

                {
                  a: "aaa",
                  b: "bbb",
                  c: "ccc",
                  d: "ddd",
                  ...
                },

                {
                  a: "aaa",
                  b: "bbb",
                  c: "ccc",
                  d: "ddd",
                  ...
                },

                {
                  a: "aaa",
                  b: "bbb",
                  c: "ccc",
                  d: "ddd",
                  ...
                },
            ];
```

Now run a loop for main array

Inside that loop through each object inside array.
Increment a counter in each turn and check it is greater than 2 then insert it in main array `myObj` again

```
$.each(myObj, function( index, value ) {
    var counter = 0;
    $.each(value, function( index2, value2 ) {
        counter++;
        if(counter > 2){
            myObj[] = value;
        }
    });

});
```

> if you have different structure for the main array of object then
>   slight change will be there